# Density of states on pymolyze

Tags: density-of-states

On the **pymolyze** program, the "calculate" panel contains : Muliken, Csquared,Density of states, overlap population and overlap DOS analysis.

While performing a DOS analysis, how can we get  the contribution of each fragment on HOMO and LUMO orbitals?